# routing to and from the parent component in angular4

Tags: angular

Senario: I have 2 component in my app. I want to load the first component on page load and the component will have a link to navigate to the second component. The second component would in turn have a link to navigate back to the first component.

I am able to route with 2 routerLink above the router-outlet and move to and fro using the link. But how can I achieve the above scenario? Any basic plunker example would help.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have achieved everything. You only need to know how to achieve the same without using `routerLink` link. So here is the solution,

- Assume `homeComponent` is the component which loads when app starts.
- It has a button to go to about page(string coming from HTML & using typescript code)
- It has a router.navigate method which takes an appropriate route name and navigate it accordingly.
- And Vice versa

**home.html**

```
<button (click)="goto('about')"> go to about page </button>
```

**home.ts**

```
import {Router} from '@angular/router'

export class HomeComponent{
    consturctor(private router:Router){}

    goto(navigateTo:string){
          this.router.navigate([navigateTo])  //this line will take you to about component
    }
}
```

---

**about.html**

```
<button (click)="goto('home')"> go to about page </button>
```

**about.ts**

```
import {Router} from '@angular/router'

export class AboutComponent{
    consturctor(private router:Router){}

    goto(navigateTo:string){
          this.router.navigate([navigateTo])  //this line will take you to home component
    }
}
```

Comment: I removed the routerLink and router-outlet is still there with the selector for the home in the app.component so that my home component is loaded with "http://localhost:4401". When i click on the button on home, the home component remains and about component gets added inside the router-outlet tag.  I don't want the home component once we navigate to about component.  How can I load my home component without changing the default url and switch between components?

Comment: You can not remove `router-outlet`. only remove `routerLink="home"` if it is there otherwise no changes reuqired.

Comment: I don't want the home component once we navigate to about component for this make sure that you have once one & one `router-outlet` in main/root component.